# Select distinct on one column only using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm developing an Entity Framework Code First library using C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I have this table on my database:

[image]

`SentBy` and `SentTo` columns are FK to a User table.

I want to get users that have sent a message to another user, but I only want to get it once. To do it, I use this SQL Statement:

```
select distinct SentBy, DateUtcSent
  from Messages where isAFriendshipRequest = 0 and SentTo = 15
order by DateUtcSent DESC;
```

I do `order by DateUtcSent DESC;` to get the latest message sent first.

The idea is to get a row for each user that has sent a message to user 15.

But I get this:

[image]

As you can see, I get user 2 twice.

I don't need the last row.

Here, I'm trying to get each different user that has sent a message to user 15, and get user id, dateUtcSent and the body on the result.

**How can I do it to don't get a sentBy value more than once?**

### **UPDATE**

And, If I want to to do the this:

```
select distinct SentTo, DateUtcSent
  from Messages where isAFriendshipRequest = 0 and SentBy = 15
order by DateUtcSent DESC;
```

And then, merge both results without repeating users and getting the last message.

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our coop, the final query is:

```
var query =
    context.Messages
    .Where(x => x.IsAFriendshipRequest == false && x.SentTo == userId).Include("SentByUser")
    .Select(x => new { User = x.SentBy, x.DateUtcSent, x.Body, Name = x.SentByUser.Name })
    .Union
    (
        context.Messages
        .Where(x => x.IsAFriendshipRequest == false && x.SentBy == userId).Include("SentToUser")
        .Select(x => new { User = x.SentTo, x.DateUtcSent, x.Body, Name = x.SentToUser.Name })
    )
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.User, x.Name})
    .Select(x => new { User = x.Key.User, DateUtcSent = x.Max(z => z.DateUtcSent), Body = x.Where(z => z.DateUtcSent == x.Max(d => d.DateUtcSent)).Select(z=>z.Body ).SingleOrDefault(), Name = x.Key.Name});
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more information about the last comment I sent you.

Comment: Check my new edit. After the union just group by again and get the max date.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but I need to get `Messages.Body` and `Users.Name`. This is how I modified your code: http://pastebin.com/azEHK5iT. It is a bit slow.

Comment: I cannot comment on the speed of it, but i made some modifications http://pastebin.com/4cKpiWiQ . I added the `Name` on the group by and then you need a `Where` to get the correct `Body` or else you would take just one `Body` in random.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work: T
The specified method 'Boolean  Max[<>f__AnonymousType1`4,Boolean](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.DateTime,System.String,System.String]], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.DateTime,System.String,System.String],System.Boolean])' in type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' can not be converted into a store expression LINQ to Entities because no overload matches the arguments passed.

Comment: I have changed SingleOrDefault with FirstOrDefault. Now it returns this: http://pastebin.com/V0FbS165. These are the messages sent to user 15, but User is wrong.

Comment: I have fixed the error with User here: http://pastebin.com/keDhddR6. Thanks a lot. It seems to work and now it's fast! I'll continue checking it with a database with more messages. You can edit your question and change your code with this one: http://pastebin.com/keDhddR6

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DistinctBy(m=> m.SentBy)`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is SQL, but I understand that you need a Linq To Sql query, so here it is:

```
var q = from message in Messages 
        where message.isAFriendshipRequest = 0 
        && message.SentTo = 15
        group message by message.SentBy into grp
        select grp.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateUtcSent).First();
```

You group by sender, order by date, and take only the first.